# How to check if a Laravel Collection is empty?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I create a view by doing an eloquent query and then pass it over to Blade.

```
@if($contacts != null)
//display contacts
@else
You dont have contacts
@endif
```

However it always assume that $contacts has something even if the query gives me nothing.

I did `dd($contacts)` and get:

```
Collection {#247 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

How do I check if it is empty?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If it is a Eloquent Collection as it appears to be from your example you can use the isEmpty collection helper function;

```
@if(!$contacts->isEmpty())
//display contacts
@else
You dont have contacts
@endif
```

[Collections Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isempty)

Answer (score 22):

There are few ways:

```
if (!empty($contacts))

if (!contacts->isEmpty())

if (count($contacts) > 0)

if ($contacts->count() > 0)
```

Comment: You'll run into issues with `count($contacts) > 0` on PHP 7.2+

Comment: if (!empty($contacts)) - This is not giving correct output

Answer (score 5):

Your Eloquent query returns an array of result, so you can use `count`.

```
@if(count($contacts) > 0)
//Display contacts
@else
//No contacts
@endif
```

Comment: It's not an array of results, it's an Eloquent Collection object that implements array interfaces.

Comment: @JeremyHarris of course you're right, I just meant the result is an array :)

Comment: this is what I needed. I was trying to check whether my url parameters were empty, using `empty($request->request)`, but that was returning `false` even when no query strings were set. Your method worked however.

Answer (score 5):

Your `$contacts` is empty. Bcoz Your query is unable to get data. Once your query unable to get data it's return an empty arrya. So check it

```
    @if($contacts->isEmpty())
    {{ 'Empty' }} 
    @else
   {{ 'you have data' }}
    @endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `blank($contacts)` 
Helpers Laravel: [blank](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-blank)

Answer (score 2):

You must do the following:

in the view of your " *ContactController* ":

```
public function index()
{
   $contacts = Contact::all();
   return view('page.index', compact('contacts'))
}
```

later on view " *index.blade.php* ":

```
@if (collect($contacts)->isEmpty()) {{-- remember that $contact is your variable --}}
   <p>There is no record available at this time</p>
@else
   @foreach($contacts as $contact)
      {{$contact->name_contact}}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Now, I suppose you have a model called **Contact**

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count($profiles) > 0){
            return redirect()->action('NameController@name');
        }else{
            return view('user');
        }
```

this also works fine in a controller

Answer (score 1):

i added method as global in my helper class

```
function isNullOrEmpty($value)
{
    return is_null($value) || empty($value);
}
```

Comment: `return is_null($value) || empty($value);` is working too hard -- this is equivalent to `return !$value`.