# How can I check if collection empty in view blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, collections, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

If I `dd($items);` in the controller, the result like this :

[image]

In the view blade laravel I check if collection empty like this :

```
@if($items)
...
@endif
```

But it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to check if an object is empty in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269198/need-to-check-if-an-object-is-empty-in-laravel)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use $items->isEmpty(); or $items->isNotEmpty();

Like so:

```
@if(!$items->isNotEmpty())
...
@endif
```

You can further read over here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-isempty

Comment: Your if statement says when not not empty.. 
Just use:
@if($items->isNotEmpty()) -> when not empty
or
@if($items->isEmpty()) -> when empty

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ( $items->count() )
....
@endif
```

Comment: add more description to your answer

Answer (score 0):

i normally double check so that if i don't get the value the page keeps running :

```
@if(isset($items))
@if(!empty($items))
.....
@endif
@endif
```

hope it helps