# search box count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to write a search code 
this is search method:

```
public function searchcontent(){
    $searchkey = \Request::get('title');
    $customer = customers::where('customer_name','like','%'.$searchkey. '%')->orderBy('id')->paginate(5);
    return view('customers.search',['customer'=>$customer]);
}
```

and this is the view

```
@if(count($customer)>0)
        @foreach($customer as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                <th>{{$user->name}}</th>
                <th>{{$user->email}}</th>
                <th>{{$user->phone}}</th>
                <th>{{$user->city}}</th>
               <tr>
       @endforeach                     
            @endif


 <form class="form-header" action="{{url('tsearchcontent')}}" method="GET">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input class="au-input au-input--xl" type="text" name="title" placeholder=",,,,." />
                    <button class="au-btn--submit" type="submit">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

and i got this error
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether or not your customer object is null before trying to invoke count().

Comment: do you mean in the database?

Comment: No, in your code. check if it is empty here is a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269198/need-to-check-if-an-object-is-empty-in-laravel

Comment: i added it .and it displayed the same error message 
@dustinos3