# Laravel how to check object empty

Tags: laravel, object

Can i check object empty?

i'm Try

```
dd($result,empty($result->Monday),is_null($result->Monday));
```

But return `false`

This my object

```
{#1041 ▼
  +"Monday": {#1038}
  +"Tuesday": {#1040 ▶}
  +"Wednesday": {#1058 ▶}
  +"Thursday": {#1060 ▶}
  +"Friday": {#1062 ▶}
  +"Saturday": {#1065 ▶}
  +"Sunday": {#1067 ▶}
}
```

Comment: This question is already being answered here is a link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269198/need-to-check-if-an-object-is-empty-in-laravel

Comment: I found it but not my answer

Comment: Did you try `!isset()` ?

Comment: i try already it can not check empty

Comment: please post the output of `dd($result->Monday);`

Comment: I can do it . By return null if the date does not contain data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave value `null` before sending the object to the view. And then go to check the `null` on the blade

```
{#1041 ▼
  +"Monday": Null
  +"Tuesday": {#1040 ▶}
  +"Wednesday": {#1058 ▶}
  +"Thursday": {#1060 ▶}
  +"Friday": {#1062 ▶}
  +"Saturday": {#1065 ▶}
  +"Sunday": {#1067 ▶}
}
```